# Asymptotic Analysis for two variables

Tags: functional-analysis, asymptotics

i have a function  $ f(x,y)= \sqrt{x^2+2xy+3y^2}$ $\space$ , and $g(x,y)= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

I have to prove that $f$ is bounded both above and below by  $g$ asymptotically $\Rightarrow f(x,y)=\Theta(g(x,y)) \Rightarrow  \text{there is c and C $\in {R_{>0}}$ so that  $c g(x,y)\leq f(x,y) \leq C g(x,y)$}$

I was only able to find  the big C , but i am still not  sure how to find the  little  c

$$ {x^{2}+2xy+3y^{2}} \leq 3x^{2}+6xy+3y^{2}= 3(x+y)^2 \leq 6(x^2+y^2)$$

$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{x^{2}+2xy+3y^{2}} \leq \sqrt{6}\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$
which means that C =$\sqrt{6}$

Any hints how can i find c

Comment: Fix $\alpha \in (0,1)$. If $\lvert y\rvert \geqslant \alpha \lvert x\rvert$, then $(x+y)^2 + 2y^2 \geqslant 2y^2 = y^2 + y^2 \geqslant \alpha^2 x^2 + y^2$. If $\lvert y\rvert < \alpha \lvert x\rvert$, then $(x+y)^2 \geqslant (1-\alpha)^2x^2$.

Comment: ok , i do understand that  , but which  value does  c take ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$c\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq \sqrt{x^2+2 x y+3 y^2}$$
square both sides
$$c^2 \left(x^2+y^2\right)\leq x^2+2 x y+3 y^2$$
expand and rearrange
$$\left(c^2-1\right) x^2-2 x y+\left(c^2-3\right) y^2\leq 0\quad(*)$$

which is true for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ if

$$\left(1-\left(c^2-1\right) \left(c^2-3\right)\right) y^2<0\land c^2-1<0$$
that is
$$-c^4+4 c^2-2<0\land c^2-1<0$$
$c^2-1<0\to -1<c<1\quad(*)$

$-c^4+4 c^2-2<0\to c^4-4c^2+2>0$

set $c^2=d$ so the inequality becomes

$d^2-4d+2>0\to d<2-\sqrt{2}\lor d>2+\sqrt{2}$

reset $d=c^2$

$c^2<2-\sqrt{2}\lor c^2>2+\sqrt{2}$

$c<-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\lor -\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}<c<\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}\lor c>\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$

recalling $(*)$ and the constraint given that $c>0$ we get $0<c<\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$

so we can take $\color{red}{c=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}$

hope this helps

$(*)$

Discriminant $\Delta=(2y)^2-4(c^2-1)(c^2-3)y^2=4y^2(1-(c^2-1)(c^2-3))$
$$
.
$$

**Edit**

Using the same technique for the right bound I found

$C=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$

which is a bit smaller than $\sqrt 6$

Comment: yeah  thnx that is  totaly understandabble,

Comment: can  you  plz give me the name of the  method , in which  you calculate discriminant  as function of  y and then the discriminant  of the obtained  function ,  becauuse i want to read about , i only do  know  how to resolve a quadratic equation with  one variable and not a conic section

Comment: @Mohbenay I added a line in my answer. There is no special method. If you have $ax^2+bxy+cy^2=0$ then to compute the discriminant you consider $y$ as a parameter and get $\Delta=b^2y^2-4acy^2$

Comment: yeah i do  understand   what  have to done  , but  iwas not sure at the beginnig to  consider y (or x) as a variable and the other one x or(y ) as a parametere,i have not thoguht  about  . thank you again

Comment: can you ply read that  and  write some comments about ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2474742/derivation-of-function-with-multiple-variables